# Floating Action Menu Like Inbox app : What is best way to implement

Tags: android, user-interface, material-design, submenu, floating-action-button

I am trying to make a floating menu like  **Inbox** app. As per the requirement , initially there should one Floating action button in bottom right corner of the Activity. I  have implement this without any  problem using material design  support library' **FloatingActionButton** class. Now the problem is when I clicked   or touch the floating Action button. In its onClick ,it should open a menu of  three more floating action button on the page just like the Inbox android app. Now how do I can implement this?

What I am thinking right now for this  is ,open a new activity with transparent background and place 4 floating action button on this. 3 for menu items and  one  for closing these action menus and return back to previous activity.
Second I can  use a fragment for the same  task.
What should I use ?Activity  or  fragment as per android design support guidlines? Please suggest a better solution if anybody have any to implement the same.